# Postman get status code 200 with no headers GET METHOD but python requests gets 500 error

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

[enter image description here][1]As a title, I can't get the content of website with `python requests`, but works with `postman`

I had tried to connect website with postman and get content of the web page,
but I couldn't  achieve it when I executed the code that was produced by postman like below, Instead, I got error `500` status code with python 2 and 3.

import requests

```
url = "https://www.screener.reuters.wallst.com/Stock/US/ResultsTable"

querystring = {"returnChoice":"","page":"2","sortBy":"RCCMultexCompanyName","sortDir":"A","quickscreen":"gaarp","criteria":"%5B%22StockUniverse%22%2C%22PriceEarnings%22%2C%22EPSGrowthRate%22%2C%22Region%22%2C%22SectorAndIndustry%22%2C%22PEGRatio%22%5D","Currency":"USD","PEGRatio":"%7B%22view%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22button_inputs%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22range_inputs%22%3A%22LSS%7C1%22%7D","SectorAndIndustry":"%7B%22industries%22%3A%5B%2257111%22%2C%2257112%22%2C%2257121%22%2C%2257131%22%2C%2257132%22%2C%2257211%22%2C%2257212%22%5D%7D","Region":"%7B%22countries%22%3A%5B%22TW%22%5D%7D","EPSGrowthRate":"%7B%22view%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22button_inputs%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22range_inputs%22%3A%22GTR%7C15%22%7D","PriceEarnings":"%7B%22view%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22button_inputs%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22range_inputs%22%3A%22GEQ%7C0%7CLEQ%7C15%22%7D","StockUniverse":"%7B%22button_inputs%22%3A%5B%22LIKE%7CUnited%2BStates%22%2C%22NOTLIKE%7CUnited%2BStates%22%5D%7D","OriginalCurrency":"USD%0A"}

headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

I excepted get 200 status code，but got 500 actually.
It is strange because postman can get right result and python cannot,even I had filled in the headers.

```
headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
    'Accept-Language': "zh-TW,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'X-Requested-With': "XMLHttpRequest",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }



The below url can get content if you connect it with browser or postman but  can't  get if you connect it with python reqeusts or urllib. 

https://www.screener.reuters.wallst.com/Stock/US/ResultsTable?returnChoice=&page=2&sortBy=RCCMultexCompanyName&sortDir=A&quickscreen=gaarp&criteria=%5B%22StockUniverse%22%2C%22PriceEarnings%22%2C%22EPSGrowthRate%22%2C%22Region%22%2C%22SectorAndIndustry%22%2C%22PEGRatio%22%5D&Currency=USD&PEGRatio=%7B%22view%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22button_inputs%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22range_inputs%22%3A%22LSS%7C1%22%7D&SectorAndIndustry=%7B%22industries%22%3A%5B%2257111%22%2C%2257112%22%2C%2257121%22%2C%2257131%22%2C%2257132%22%2C%2257211%22%2C%2257212%22%5D%7D&Region=%7B%22countries%22%3A%5B%22TW%22%5D%7D&EPSGrowthRate=%7B%22view%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22button_inputs%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22range_inputs%22%3A%22GTR%7C15%22%7D&PriceEarnings=%7B%22view%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22button_inputs%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22range_inputs%22%3A%22GEQ%7C0%7CLEQ%7C15%22%7D&StockUniverse=%7B%22button_inputs%22%3A%5B%22LIKE%7CUnited%2BStates%22%2C%22NOTLIKE%7CUnited%2BStates%22%5D%7D&OriginalCurrency=USD

And below is postman screenshot
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO8ev.png
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the website itself

Comment: I am not sure if the url is internal one or not but I am getting site error while accessing the url you have specified. From where are you running the python script ? Also try to do nslookup for that url from where you are running the script

Comment: I tried to run  script on pycharm with python2 and online (in https://repl.it/languages/python3)
The strange thing is I can get content with postman
What are different between postman and pycharm with no headers?

Comment: I think the reason is cookie. I cannot redo it on another computer and postman.   The question is why the postman cant get correct result, is there anywhere postman can save cookie even with not headers an no environment?

Answer (score 0):

I found postman will store cookie secretly  even if cookies doesn't present in the python code which is postman generated with new desktop postman version.

The way to get right content is to requests post below url with corrent params
https://www.screener.reuters.wallst.com/Stock/US/Results
It will get 500 error,but with this session I can get the content of my question.